# RDP like tool on Ubuntu

Tags: rdp

Just migrated from Windows to Linux. Now I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
My work requires to manage multiple servers with Windows on board, so I create many RDP connections.
Often I need to connect to PC placed in my workplace from Windows PC at home. When I was on Windows I used RDP for this.
But on Linux it became more difficult. I need RDP like tool which will help me to connect from Windows to Linux and solve problems in list below:

- GUI, console is not enough because of reason above
- connect to workplace PC in same session as I leave it
- prevent anybody to see what I'm doing

I already tried:

- **x11vnc**. Nice but I can't find the way to block local display and input devices
- **xrdp**. Good but it does not support 3d desktops and I have problems to use keyboard in xrdp session
- **nomachine**. Same as x11vnc.

Is there way to get what I need?

**UPD.** The best solution I could find for today described in this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1ay7toiJ6k&feature=youtu.be&list=UU2T42eA_KqVx9P4W5xUOw0Q). Best but not ideal.

Comment: ssh or a web interface (webmin) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problems is `remmina`.

You should install this package first. After that start the GUI and create as many connection profiles you need using RDP protocol choice.

Good luck and let us know how it works for you!

Comment: Remmina comes pre-installed, IIRC.

Comment: Isn't remmina automatically installed with 14.04?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course I use _remmina_ when I sit at my work PC. My problem is to connect from 'home Windows' to 'work Linux' as convinient as I did it when both PCs have Windows installed.

Comment: Do you want to connect linux box using RDP?

Comment: Yep. I already can to connect to Linux via RDP. But I want to find more native and convenient solution if any exists.

Answer (score -1):

you can use rdesktop install that package and run below command syntax

$ rdesktop -g 1400x1000 < remotehostname > or < IPADDress >